# Java Vowel counter using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, counter

I'm doing an online CPS course and a question requires me to write a code that counts the vowels(upper and lowercase) in a string. Here is my code:

```
    public static int countVowels( String s )
    {
        {
        if ( s.length() == 0 )
          return 0 + countVowels(s);
        else if ( (s.substring(0, 1) == "a" ) || (s.substring(0, 1) == "A") ) 
          return 1 + countVowels(s.substring(1));
        else if ( (s.substring(0, 1) == "e" ) || (s.substring(0, 1) == "E") ) 
          return 1 + countVowels(s.substring(1));
        else if ( (s.substring(0, 1) == "i" ) || (s.substring(0, 1) == "I") ) 
          return 1 + countVowels(s.substring(1));
        else if ( (s.substring(0, 1) == "o" ) || (s.substring(0, 1) == "O") ) 
          return 1 + countVowels(s.substring(1));
        else if ( (s.substring(0, 1) == "u" ) || (s.substring(0, 1) == "U") ) 
          return 1 + countVowels(s.substring(1));
        }

        return countVowels(s.substring(1));
    }
```

but I'm getting a "StackOverFlow" error and I'm not sure what to do. I know that the error means that the terminating condition isn't being reached. I'm not allowed to use anything that I haven't learned yet and I'm also not allowed to use for or while statements because this is a recursion problem.

Could I please get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case when `s.length() == 0` you are causing an infinite recursion. An empty string has 0 vowels, so you should edit 5th line to `return 0;` Another thing to watch out for: you're comparing strings with `==`. This operator is intended for something else. Use `equals` instead. Take a look at this, for example: [String comparison](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html). That is `s.substring(0, 1) == "a"` should become `s.substring(0, 1).equals("a")`

As a matter of fact, there are some other pieces of advice I'd give you, like just storing the first letter in the string, instead of calculating it in every case (twice at that). Also, you  can get the lower case character for the first character, so that you can reduce the cases you compare to twice. Also, add vowels to an array, this code is not DRY.

Comment: Okay, I did that but then my program always returns 0 as the output.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean :/

Comment: I just don't know how to convert what you wrote to into code to edit my program

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thank you so very much!!! You're so knowledgable! I hope to become like you one day :)

Comment: @Rohan You should hope to become more knowledgeable than the best people in StackOverflow, who happen to be way more knowledgeable than me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution in javascript. You can test it by creating a file 'something.html' and opening it in your browser.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="input">
</div>
<div id='answer'> 
</div>
<script>
var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
var testInput = 'Hello this is just a test. Out with it.';

function Contains(value, inArray) {
    var found = false;  
    for(var j=0, size = inArray.length; j < size; j++) {
        if(value.toLowerCase() === inArray[j]) {
        found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

var vowelCounter = 0;
    for(var i=0, j = testInput.length; i < j; i++) {
        if(Contains(testInput[i], vowels)) {
        vowelCounter +=1;
        }
    }

    var inp = document.getElementById("input");
    inp.innerHTML = 'Question <br/>' + testInput;

    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'Number of Vowels: ' + vowelCounter;

</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer baffles me for at least three reasons; can you identify those reasons?

Comment: lol. I agree its not well written, not looking at edge cases. The algorithm used is the definition of 'brute force', and in many ways does not directly address the recursion problem. But using it, the op is atleast sure that the logic is right, so he can strictly then focus on what/where he is making a mistake in terms of understanding/using recursion.

Comment: Seems odd for a recursive Java question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope by now you would have completed your homework. I have solved the same problem in a shorter way:

```
public class CountVowels {
    private static String vowels = "aeiou";
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "RohanAskedAQuestion";
        System.out.println(recursivelyCountVowels(s));
    }

    private static int recursivelyCountVowels(String s) {
        if(s==null||s.length()==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(vowels.contains((CharSequence) s.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase())){
            return 1+recursivelyCountVowels(s.substring(1));
        }
        return 0+recursivelyCountVowels(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :) , I am also learning java so if anybody has any suggestion please do tell.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a little late but still :)

```
public int recursiveCountVowels(String str,int count,int currentPosition)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    if(str.trim().length() == 0)
        return count;

    if(currentPosition == str.length())
        return count;

    for(int i = currentPosition ; i < str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u')
            count++;
            currentPosition++;
    }

    return recursiveCountVowels(str, count, currentPosition);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

vowel count (vc) - Return the number of vowels in an input string.

```
public static int vc(String s)
{
    if(s.length() - 1 < 0) return 0;
    return((("aeiou".indexOf((s.charAt(s.length()-1)+"").toLowerCase()) >= 0 ? 1 : 0)) 
           + vc((s = s.substring(0,s.length()-1))));
}
```